# Using close vote on question versus within review queue?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't find any guidance on this from previous questions. I have from time to time chose to hit the close button within a question which then may or may receive other votes to close from other users.

I then see that I cannot vote on it via queue, which makes sense. However if the question is eventually closed, I do not see that I receive a close vote in my tally for the day or overall total with the close vote stats.

It appears if I vote close only in queue review I receive a tally and not if I chose to vote close within a question and then it eventually is vote on to be closed by the other moderators.

How does this process work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a closer look at the Badge Process (if you click on your review tally) it talks about badges being awarded once per review queue.  The tally is recording the number of review queue reviews you make (of each type), not what you vote to do on a particular Q&A.  It doesn't count whether you vote to close or not, it counts that you completed a review.  You could vote to leave every Close review question open, it would still count them in your close review tally.

[image]

Your tally hasn't gone up in this case as you haven't actually made a review, you've just voted to close on a question itself.

Comment: I suppose I want to be able to click on the close button on the question and receive a tally in review because in my mind I've reviewed the question and chose to vote to close it. However, I understand what you mean.